# Скудость и скудность

Tags: семантика, синонимы

Верно ли, что:

**Скудность** - бедность, ограниченность (рациона пищи, содержания информации и других явлений не относящихся к человеку непосредственно).
**Скудость** - ограниченность, убогость (ума, мысли, и прочих явлений относящихся к человеку напрямую).

И будет ли искажением начального смысла, употребляя их в противоположных друг другу примерах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скудость - это малое количество, а скудность - низкое качество, определяемое малым количеством.

Поэтому скудость ума, образования, научных кадров, мысли, бюджета, но: скудность обстановки, еды, пайка, грунта, рифм.

Answer (score 2):

Скудость -  разг. То же, что: скудность.  Толковый словарь Ефремовой. 
См.также словарь под редакцией Кузнецова.
[image]